# UITextfield in UITableview with Calendar value

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, calendar

I have a question about populating UITableViewCell with the selected value in calendar. So i have this tableview which is of course created when the view appears, and as i said i also i have this calendar view controller. The main idea is that users can select a date on the calendar, and after that that value should appear in the text field in tableview.

I've have a function that is returning the selected value from the calendars view controller to that other view controller, but after that i can't populate the UITextField with that value.

Any idea or previous similar experience?

Here is the code that is used in the calendar view controller

```
-(void)giveString:(NSString*)string{
GradesViewController *grades = [[GradesViewController alloc]init];
[grades getString:string];
NSLog(@"String : %@",string);}
```

and here is the class in that other view in which i want this string value from calendar in my textfield located in tableviewcell

```
-(void)getString:(NSString*)string{
stringDate = string;
NSLog(@"String: %@",stringDate);}
```

the both values appear in log...

Comment: What do you mean "can't populate"?  How have you tried it?  Can we see some sample code please?

Comment: I have edited the question, and added the main parts of it...

Answer (score 0):

You are never retaining "string" in `[GradesViewController getString:string]`

```
-(void)getString:(NSString*)string {
    stringDate = string;
    [stringDate retain];
    NSLog(@"String: %@",stringDate);
}
```

Make sure it's released as well in order to ensure that garbage collection will clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `stringDate` value in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, if you are declared that textfield in your `tableviewcell cellForRowAtIndexpath`. If you are using custom tableviewcell, you need to pass that value to you custome `tableView` cell class, like how you are calling from `CalendarViewController` to other `ViewController`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell *tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
     if (tableCell == nil) {
        tableCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        UITextField *urlTxtFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 230, 120)];

        urlTxtFld.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        urlTxtFld.text = stringDate // you need to set your text like this
        urlTxtFld.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [qrCell addSubview:urlTxtView];
        [urlTxtFld release];
    }

 }
```